# Unable to run spring boot application on openshift

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift, web-deployment, openshift-online

I have deployed a spring boot project on open shift stater gen 3. It was perfectly a few days ago. But yesterday I rebuilt it and it gave me this "Application is not available".I deployed it through this.
[Redhat open JDK 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xamzb.png)

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.spring.universitysystem</groupId>
<artifactId>university-system</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>university-system</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc42</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/activation-1.1.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It was fine a few days ago, and suddenly it not runable anymore

Build log on the server
[Build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvpNC.png)

Deployment log
[Deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuztI.png)

The build and deployment is working just fine no error at all

Comment: If you use ``oc rsh`` to get into the container, or you use the web console to get a terminal, does ``curl http://localhost:8080`` provide a response? Then try ``curl http://$HOSTNAME:8080``. Finally, have you tried triggering a new deployment by clicking on _Deploy_ on the deployment configuration in the web console to see if that helps.

Comment: I tried  `curl http://localhost:8080` and  `curl http://$HOSTNAME:8080`. None of them gives me a response. I also tried to redeploy as your suggestion. Maybe openshift has trouble with their services.

Comment: I read some posts said that wait for few days and it will fine. Don't know it is true or not but I also tried to deploy another project but still the same result

Comment: Back last year the Online Starter environments were having issues, but they don't have issues to the extent they did back then. If you are using ``us-east-1``, they do state that it is having some issues at present, but in general they should work okay. Seen one over report of routes not working on ``ca-central-1``. Which cluster are you on? Always check the status page. https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: My cluster is `ca-central-1`, I also check the status every day but didn't see the report of routes not working. Where did you find it?

Comment: Saw another using having similar issues. I will put out a query to see if can find out what issue is.

Comment: Try doing this: ``oc scale --replicas=0 dc <deploymentconfig>`` and then ``oc scale --replicas=1 dc <deploymentconfig>``. Replace ``<deploymentconfig>`` with actual deployment config name. A feature relating to idle inactive apps was recently turned on and is possible that is causing the issue. Scaling down and then scaling up to manually reset idle state may work. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/idling_applications.html#idling-applications-unidling-applications

Comment: I tried scaling down and up, it still doesn't work. The deployment on the pod is the same with the deployment [link](https://imgur.com/a/qYDAP)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this has possibly been fixed up now, so try and see if things are working.

Comment: Tks, it works now :D